# wbadmin doesn't run as scheduled task

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, wbadmin

Continued from: [wbadmin system state backup fails](https://serverfault.com/questions/172349/wbadmin-system-state-backup-fails)

When I put the following a bat file and run it as scheduled task, I see that the webadmin.exe process starts but it never seems to create backup:

```
wbadmin start systemstatebackup -backuptarget:\\server\foo -quiet
```

This seems to run fine when I run the bat file directly. I have the scheduled task configured to run with the "highest privileges". The share doesn't use windows authentication but it is a mapped network drive.

Comment: Also I see some posts on the internet about `-user` parameter which seems to be absent from my version ...

Comment: Throwing in a net use command to bat file to see if that helps for some reason ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems adding the net use command before fixed it, so it must have something to do with creating a new session for the scheduled task.  The command was something like:

```
net use \\backupServer\backups /u:backupUser shhhSecret
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems with NTBackup in the past when it was scheduled to run under the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user because it doesn't have any network permissions whatsoever, so just hung indefinitely.

To fix the problem, I had to run the scheduled task under my own user account.